# longtable+ltxtable = ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: errors, longtable, ltxtable

How to fix it?

I lost any & or newline ?

The error:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.16            h1 &
         h2 & h3 \\
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{booktabs}         % to improve tables
\usepackage{tabularx}           % to add width in tables
\usepackage{ltxtable}           % to mixing tabularx + longtable
\usepackage{longtable}          % to permit big tables over pages
\usepackage{multirow}           % to set multirows in tables

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{cXX}
        \label{tab:qualityCriteria} \\
    \caption{Criteria to qualify.} \\
    \toprule

        h1 & h2 & h3 \\

    \midrule
    \endhead

        c1 & c2 & c3 \\

        c4 & c5 & c6 \\

    \bottomrule

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand what's happening with `ltxtable` and `longtable`, but I suggest loading `ltablex` which seems to have the same functionality (extending the capabilities of `longtable` to `tabularx`), and allows your code to work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % to improve tables
\usepackage{ltablex} % to mixing tabularx + longtable
\usepackage{multirow} % to set multirows in tables

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]\keepXColumns
  \begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{cXX}
    \label{tab:qualityCriteria} \\
    \caption{Criteria to qualify.} \\
    \toprule
    h1 & h2 & h3 \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    c1 & c2 & c3 \\
    c4 & c5 & c6 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The better answer. Maybe the table enviroment can be deleted and, only use the second enviroment, the tabularx...

Comment: Another point that resolve my question was this: the `ltxtable package` should be used with 2 different texs files where, first is the main, and the second is the table itself. AND the main tex should refers to the table by the command `\LTXtable`